# Raspbian Stretch lite headless, wifi not connecting

Tags: pi-3, wifi, headless

Am using a Pi model 3 and the latest (2018-06-27) Raspbian Stretch lite, and have only added `wpa_supplicant.conf` (below) and `ssh` (empty) in the "boot" partition.

```
country=*CODE*
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

network={
    ssid=*NAME*
    psk=*PASSWORD*
}
```

The machine never connects to the router.

**Edit**: thought maybe it was [this problem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1291820):

> I think you're running into a race condition between the service which
>   copies wpa_supplicant.conf and the one that checks whether the wifi
>   country is set. Unfortunately the image doesn't have the fix in it
>   yet.

but apparently not.

How do I get Stretch lite to support headless wifi?

Any other OS distro that is known to work headless out of the box?

Comment: You should paste your files INTO THE QUESTION. What model Pi?

Comment: What country is "*CODE*"

Comment: list the ACTUAL contents of your file, or edit it if you haven’t

Comment: Have you tried the solution suggested in the post? `sudo bash -c "echo '0' > /var/lib/systemd/rfkill/platform-3f300000.mmc:wlan"`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: I saw it, but that whole directory (`rfkill`) does not exist.

Comment: No need to worry about that race condition. It is fixed since version 2018-04-18: [release_notes](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt).

Comment: In the `ssid=*NAME*` and `psk=*PASSWORD*`, you're supposed to put the SSID and password in quotes, so the SSID "example_wifi" would be used this way: `ssid="example_wifi"`. I'm sure that's the problem.